# JavaFX Line not moving as it should

Tags: java, javafx

I've recently started using JavaFX and i've been having some errors getting a line object to move as it should. I have the following code for my line.

```
Line line1 = new Line();
        line1.setStartX(100.0);
        line1.setStartY(150.0);
        line1.setEndX(500.0);
        line1.setEndY(150.0);
```

I then add the said line to my GridPane by using gridPane.getChildren().addAll(line1); along with labels I used earlier in the program.
[image]

As you can see, the line is always at the top of the program, regardless of what parameters I enter. I believe I am properly setting up the line, so it may be a gridpane issue? I was hoping for help in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `getChildren()` for `GridPane`. It is better to use `add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex)` or `add(Node child, int columnIndex, int rowIndex, int colspan, int rowspan)`.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Based on the problem we can figure a suitable solution

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from a **misplacement of your component** into the GridPane. You forgot indicating the row index of your line, so it places it on the first cell (rowIndex=0, columnIndex=0).

By the way, instead of writing:

```
Label anyLabel = new Label("Something");
GridPane.setRowIndex(anyLabel, y);
GridPane.setColumnIndex(anyLabel, x);

gridPane.getChrildren().add(anyLabel, ... /* other JavaFX components */);
```

I suggest you to always write:

```
Label anyLabel = new Label("Something");
gridPane.add(anyLabel, y, x);
```

With that syntax you cannot forget any component's placement into `gridPane`.